# Z-value Error in ArcGIS Collector

Tags: arcgis-online, error, feature-layer, arcgis-collector, z-value

I have a feature layer found in this map: http://arcg.is/0L8SS5  which is to be used with Collector as a part of a classroom activity.  The feature layer is producing the error message "The shape must have a Z value".

Is the only solution to this error to recreate the feature layer without a z value and republish or can settings be adjusted in AGOL to prevent this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you can set a default value for the z values through the admin API which might resolve your issue. Check out this support link http://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000014234

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I just made the change to the service URL.  When I went in and made the edits to the points they did not revert.  I will be able to check tomorrow to see if the students can do the same.

Answer (score 1):

That is accurate:

[How To: Remove Z- and/or M-values from a feature class](http://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000010389)

> Instructions provided describe how to create a copy of a feature class and disable M- and Z-value associations for the output feature class. These associations cannot be removed from an existing feature class. 
>   M-values are routing values.
>   Z-values are elevation values.

**Note:
ArcGIS Mobile Services cannot contain M or Z enabled feature layers.**

Procedure

- Browse to ArcToolbox > Conversion Tools > To Geodatabase.
- Open the Feature Class to Geodatabase (multiple) tool.
- Add all the feature classes into the Input Feature Class parameter.
- Select an Output Geodatabase.
- Click the Environments button at the bottom of the tool dialog box.
- Expand the General Settings.
- For the parameter, Output has Z Values, change the value to Disabled.
- For the parameter, Output has M Values, change the value to Disabled.
- Click OK in the Environments dialog box.
- Click OK to execute the geoprocessing tool.

Comment: According to this I am understanding that we will need to publish new layers without z-values. ("These associations cannot be removed from an existing feature class.")  Is that correct?  Not all students are receiving this error and all followed the same procedure in creating them.  Could their be some issue with connectivity if some students are able to access data or wifi more easily than others?

Comment: It's possible there are some connectivity issues, but yes you would have to publish new layers to not include the z-values.